# How can I launch Thunderbird from Command Line and Auto Check IMAP Email?

Tags: thunderbird

I want to use Thunderbird as an IMAP client to backup Gmail and would prefer to run it from a CRON... Basically want to wake it up, sync IMAP folders than shutdown... I tried offlineIMAP with no success and it seems that Thunderbird is a reasonable solution.

What would the command line settings be to have it check, download, then shutdown?

Comment: If you want to backup Gmail you need to use POP not IMAP as IMAP only shows you what is on your server it doesn't download anything.

Comment: @Allan, that isn't strictly true. You can download IMAP content for later use, however, if a message is deleted from Gmail, when you sync your local imap it'll be deleted locally, too.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps fetchmail would be better suited to what you're trying to accomplish?
http://www.fetchmail.info/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can launch Thunderbird by just typing `thunderbird` in the terminal.  As to auto checking, I believe Thunderbird has an option (burred in the settings somewhere) to check for new mail at start up. Also be sure that you're fetching the entire messages with IMAP and not just the headers.  Otherwise it wont exactly be a backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to backup your Gmail account, maybe should you [have a look at this post](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/tool-to-backup-restore-gmail-emails-in.html).
It's about the [Backup Gmail](https://launchpad.net/backup-gmail/+download) script.
You can also set up automated incremental backups if i'm right (haven't personally tested it).

```
Usage: backup_gmail.py backup_dir email@address password

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -r, --restore         Restore backup to online gmail account
  -i, --inc             Use incremental backup
  -k, --keep_status     Keep the mail read status (Slow)
  -s START_DATE, --start=START_DATE
                        Backup mail starting from this date. Format:
                        30-Jan-2010
  -e END_DATE, --end=END_DATE
                        Backup mail until to this date Format: 30-Jan-2010
  --include=INCLUDE_LABELS
                        Only backup these labels. Separate labels by '^'
                        Format: label1^label2
  --exclude=EXCLUDE_LABELS
                        Do not backup these labels. If --include is used this
                        flag will be ignored. Separate labels by '^' Format:
                        label1^label2
  -c CONFIG_FILE, --config=CONFIG_FILE
                        Load setting from config file
  -p PROFILE, --profile=PROFILE
                        Use this profile in the config file.
```